# Find common characters between two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to print the common letters from two different user inputs **using a `for` loop**. (I need to do it using a for loop.) I am running into two problems: 1. My statement "If char not in output..." is not pulling unique values. 2. The output is giving me a list of individual letters rather than a single string.  I tried the split the output but split ran into a type error.

```
wrd = 'one'
sec_wrd = 'toe'

def unique_letters(x): 
    output =[]
    for char in x: 
        if char not in output and char != " ": 
            output.append(char)
    return output

final_output = (unique_letters(wrd) + unique_letters(sec_wrd))

print(sorted(final_output))
```

Comment: what  is your expected result for above code?

Comment: unique_letters(wrd) returning unique letters ? how is it not working?

Comment: expected result is 'eo'

Comment: For your second problem, when you append to output you append individual letters to list so output is a list of individual letters. In the end when you add two output list you get a concatenated list of two sublist.

Comment: @JessMatthews, and why `n` and `t` are thrown away as non-unique?

Comment: You are looking for letters that are in both strings?

Comment: `print(''.join(unique_letters(wrd + sec_wrd)))`.

Comment: I think the problem might be that output is in your function. So when you call the function a new output empty list is created. Put it out.

Comment: @JessMatthews, perhaps, change your title and question to: "find common items between 2 lists"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to perform the [Set Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)). Python has [**`set.intersection`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method for the same. You can use it for your use-case as:

```
>>> word_1 = 'one'
>>> word_2 = 'toe'

#    v join the intersection of `set`s to get back the string
#    v                             v  No need to type-cast it to `set`.
#    v                             v  Python takes care of it
>>> ''.join(set(word_1).intersection(word_2))
'oe'
```

[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) will return the unique characters in your string. `set.intersection` method will return the characters which are common in both the sets.

---

If `for` loop is must for you, then you may use a *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> unique_1 = [w for w in set(word_1) if w in word_2]
# OR
# >>> unique_2 = [w for w in set(word_2) if w in word_1]

>>> ''.join(unique_1)  # Or, ''.join(unique_2)
'oe'
```

Above result could also be achieved with explicit `for` loop as:

```
my_str = ''
for w in set(word_1):
    if w in word_2:
        my_str += w

# where `my_str` will hold `'oe'`
```

Comment: Great!  When I convert the inputs using .lower (to avoid user input errors) I am getting an error in the list comprehension line.  Any idea why?

Comment: @JessMatthews Do you mean `.lower()` ??

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of problem, you're probably better off using sets:

```
wrd = 'one'
sec_wrd = 'toe'
wrd = set(wrd)
sec_wrd = set(sec_wrd)

print(''.join(sorted(wrd.intersection(sec_wrd))))
```

Comment: I appreciate it.  I need to use a for loop.  I have tried to use intersection in the loop, but haven't gotten that to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this today on code signal. It worked for all tests.

```
def solution(s1, s2):

    common_char = ""
    for i in s1:
        if i not in common_char:
        
            i_in_s1 = s1.count(i)
            i_in_s2 = s2.count(i)
        
            comm_num = []
            comm_num.append(i_in_s1)
            comm_num.append(i_in_s2)
        
            comm_i = min(comm_num)
            new_char = i * comm_i
            common_char += new_char
    
  
    return len(common_char)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Function to solve the problem**

```
def find_common_characters(msg1,msg2):
    #to remove duplication set() is used.
    set1=set(msg1)
    set2=set(msg2)
    remove={" "}
    #if you wish to exclude space
    set3=(set1&set2)-remove
    msg=''.join(set3)
    return msg
```

**Providing input and Calling the function**
**Provide different values for msg1,msg2 and test your program**

```
msg1="python"
msg2="Python"
common_characters=find_common_characters(msg1,msg2)
print(common_characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your one line code if you want the number of common character between them!

```
def solution(s1,s2):
 return sum(min(s1.count(x),s2.count(x)) for x in set(s1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code returns a single string with the common letters sorted alphabetically. In this case, the output will be "eo":

```
wrd = 'one'
sec_wrd = 'toe'

def unique_letters(wrd, sec_wrd): 
 
    wrd1_set = set(wrd)
    sec_wrd_set = set(sec_wrd)

    output = ''.join(sorted(wrd1_set & sec_wrd_set) )
    return output

print(unique_letters(wrd, sec_wrd))
```