# Find out if any two sets have the same membership

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have six sets, named s1 ... s6, each with a few hundred string elements.

I want to test to see if any of them have the same set of elements as any others.  How might I set this up?

For what it's worth, I started out with this, to try to print the index of one offender:

```
setlist = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6]

for i in range(len(setlist)):
    if any([setlist[i] == st for st in setlist[i+1:]]):
        print('You have redundant sets: %i' % i)
```

For clarification, s1 - s6 are all of the type set().  I need to be able to see which ones match up, so e.g., if s2 and s3 happen to have the same members, I would like to see `'You have redundant sets: s2, s3'`  Obviously, my starting code won't get me there.

Comment: Do you need to know the offender(s) or just whether there is any?

Comment: And please add example input+output.

Comment: Perhaps using the builtin [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) type would be what you want?  [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611525/find-common-characters-between-two-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    s1={1,2,3}
    s2={2,3,4}
    s3={1,2,3}
    s4={1,2,3}
    s5={2,6,7}
    setlist = [s1, s2, s3, s4,s5]
    redundantSet=set()
    for i in range(len(setlist)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(setlist)):
            if(setlist[i]==setlist[j]):
                if(i==0):
                    redundantSet.add(i)
                redundantSet.add(j)
    print('You have redundant sets at index' + str(redundantSet))
```

You cannot use any() function for equating values as any() takes only list and will return true even if one element is there in the list. So even doing like this

```
any[(setlist[i+1:],setlist[i])
```

is going to return true because "setlist[i]" element will be there. Hence, will return true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the set pairs that have elements in common this should help. You'll want to use the built-in set functions rather than doing an element-wise comparison.

```
have_overlap = list()
setlist = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]
for ix1,s in enumerate(setlist):
  for ix2 in range(ix+1, len(setlist)):
    if s.symmetric_difference(setlist [ix2]):
      have_overlap.append(ix, ix2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use set built-in data structures and compare each set. For that you may put all your sets into a dictionary and give the keys as (1,2,3,5,6).
To reach all permutations for comparision you may use itertools.product such as:

```
import itertools
sets_1 = range(1,7)
sets_2 = range(1,7)
perms = list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, [(a,b) if a!= b else 0 for (a, b) in list(itertools.product(*[sets_1, sets_2]))]))
```

by using the perms you can perform set intersection like:

```
sets_dict= {1:{2,3}, 2:{5,6}, 3:{7,8}, 4:{5,9}, 5:{10,22}, 6:{22,4}}
for (set_1, set_2) in perms:
    print(sets_dict[set_1] & sets_dict[set_2])
```

Or if your sets are way too big, you may loop through each set and fill a dictionary where the keys are the set members and the values are being the sets hosting them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do so. You can iterate over the number of sets, and for every 2 sets, check if they are disjoint or not.

```
s1.isdisjoint(s2)
```

The above function returns True if no element is common in the 2 sets.

```
s1 & s2
```

The above expression returns the common elements in set s1 and s2.

```
any(i in s1 for i in s2)
```

The above generator expression expression returns a boolean value True if an element is common in the 2 sets. For all of the above expressions, the generator expression is the fastest. The second fastest is the `isdisjoint()` function. Set intersection `s1 & s2` takes the maximum time, and hence is the slowest.